# Convert DYNAMIC String to language selected

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to internationalize my app. All the strings in my `string.xml` changes when I select different language. But I have string saved in `SharedPreference`, so when I change my language, changes don't apply on my string that saved in my `SharedPreference`. Is there a way? Thanks in advance.

For example:

I save the date that the user pick from my date picker:

```
(English) Thursday, June 17 at 10:00 AM
```

When I change my language settings it is suppose to be:

```
(Spanish) Jueves, Junio 19 en 10:00 AM
```

But still it is in English,

Comment: is the saved string located in your string.xml?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin No. it is in my SharedPreference. Actually it's a date. when the user pick a date from my datepicker I saved it to a string and pass the value from different views.

Comment: Try formatting String to Locale http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#format(java.util.Locale,java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)

Comment: @rubberdont can you post what you currently saved in your SharedPreference and expected result from it

Answer (score 1):

When you saved the date to the `SavedPreferences` you need to convert it to `millisecond` and then by the time you grab the date in the `SavedPreferences` as `millisecond` you then supply it to the constructor of your Date class.

**sample:**

save it as millisecond(`value`) to the `SavedPreferences`.

```
long value = new Date().getTime(); //where it is english at this time
```

get the value from `SavedPreferences` and supply it to the constructor of Date class

```
//after you change language
long value = //get the value from SavedPreferences
Date d = new Date(value); 
d.toString(); //now the result will be the language you specified
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I came for a better solution because of your idea. It is in my own implementation. But I can't get any solution on how to auto convert string from a SharePreference. Maybe it's in the way how you saved it. Thanks alot!